# Why does my nested loop does not continue onto the next line of code? Can someone explain?

Tags: python

so I created a nested loop and everything works great until it finishes, '#3', my third 'if' statement. After that, it does not continue to the, 'else' function and does not loop to the first, 'if', statement. Can anyone explain this?

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui as pg
import time
from selenium import webdriver

time.sleep(2)
while True:

if pg.locateOnScreen('battle.png') != None: #1
    pg.click('battle.png')
    time.sleep(3)
    pg.click('continue.png')

    while True:
        if pg.locateOnScreen('attack.png') != None: #2
            time.sleep(2)
            pg.click('attack.png')
            time.sleep(4)
            pg.click('continue_2.png')

        if pg.locateOnScreen('return.png',confidence = 0.8) != None:  #3
            pg.click('return.png')
            pg.press('s')
            pg.press('w')
            time.sleep(3)
            
else:
    pg.press('s')
    pg.press('w')
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: You are locked inside inner loop which is an infinite loop and you don't have explicit `break`s.

Comment: Also, as it shows in the code window, your indentation is off.  Did you even run this through any debugger? I cannot imagine you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because both loops are always true. Once the second loop is reached, it never leaves because `True` is always `True`, meaning the else will never be reached. Try seeing if you can write the code without the nested loop.

Comment: Thank you for this! This clears things up for me!!